# template<> syntax required by Solaris CC, but forbidden by MSVC and GCC

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, cc

I have the following code in the header file:

```
template<typename A, typename B>  class TemplateTest;

template<>
class TemplateTest<int, double>
{
public:
    float operator() (float a);
};
```

The definition in the cpp file:

```
template<>   // this is problematic line
float TemplateTest<int, double>::operator()(float a)
{
    float b;
    b = a + 5;
    return b;
}
```

with the "template<>" in the definition, MSVC returns error C2910 as it interprets operator() as a template method instead of a method of a template class. GCC behaves similar. But Solaris CC requires the "template<>" (otherwise it issues error ' "template<>" syntax is required when explicitly specializing a member of ...'.

So my question is which one is correct and how to make the code compile on all these platforms.

Comment: make sure to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: @bolov That advice only applies to definitions that have at least one template parameter. This specialized `operator()` definition has none.

Answer (score 2):

Solaris CC is incorrect.  The `template<>` is not permitted.  C++14 Standard [temp.expl.spec]/5:

> Members of an explicitly specialized class template are defined in the same manner as members of normal classes, and not using the `template<>` syntax. ...
>
> [ *Example:*

```
template<class T> struct A {
  struct B { };
  template<class U> struct C { };
};

template<> struct A<int> {
  void f(int);
};

void h() {
  A<int> a;
  a.f(16);    // A<int>::f must be defined somewhere
}

// template<> not used for a member of an
// explicitly specialized class template
void A<int>::f(int) { /*...*/ }
```

> ... - *end example* ]

It looks like to support Solaris CC, you will have to use something like:

```
#ifdef __SUNPRO_CC
template <>
#endif
float TemplateTest<int, double>::operator()(float a)
{
    float b;
    b = a + 5;
    return b;
}
```

If you have a lot of these, you may want to put that boilerplate into a custom macro.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need

```
template<>   // this is problematic line
```

Full example:

```
template<typename A, typename B>  class TemplateTest;

template<>
class TemplateTest<int, double>
{
public:
    float operator() (float a);
};

float TemplateTest<int, double>::operator()(float a)
{
    return 0;
}
```

[Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bGDvifkkppaaarYo)

Look for "Members of specializations" in [C++ Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization)